# At/for the first time

Tags: meaning

What is meaning and difference between **at the first time** and **for the first time** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In this sentence:

> I've understood for the first time what you have been going through.

**for the first time** there means "I have never understood your hardship or your suffering before, but now I do".

**For the first time** refers to a new or novel experience.

**(at) the first time** would be using when referring to the first in a *series* of events or occasions.

> We have been to the zoo many times over the years, and the animals are
>   always interesting, but it is never as much fun as it was **at the first
>   time** we went.  When you go to the zoo **for the first time**, you do not know what to expect, and the surprise adds to the fun.

The word **at** is not required:

..it is never as much fun as it was *the first time* we went.

Comment: I wouldn't expect ***at*** to be present at all in *never as much fun **as it was the first time***. I realise at least some of the claimed 115,000 instances of [as it was the first time](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+it+was+the+first+time%22) will be for the sense ***as = since***, but a good proportion will match the current context. And there are only 5 instances of [as it was **at** the first time](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+it+was+at+the+first+time%22).

Comment: I do not say "**at** the first time" myself, but quite a few people do, and if encountered in the wild (or at the zoo) it would mean "on the first occasion".

Comment: Here's an example from a prior century, but in my regional dialect, many people still say it:  https://books.google.com/books?id=gYsPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA341&dq=%22at+the+first+time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4-sur7YzRAhUCNiYKHWBnCmYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22at%20the%20first%20time%22&f=false

Comment: Well, if it sounds good (or at least, "okay") to you as a native speaker, I won't try to change your opinion on that score. But the evidence from my GB searches suggests it's *always* been an extremely minority usage, so it's probably not something a learner would want to come out with today. Whatever - I'd downvoted before typing the first comment, but retracted now I see you've edited in *the word **at** is not required*. If that's the strongest phrasing you're comfortable with, hopefully my comment can remain there to present a somewhat different perspective.

Comment: How do you feel about "yiz" for second person plural?

Comment: I've never seen it written that way. Quite a few dialectal/substandard UK speakers append /z/ to the standard ***you*** in plural contexts, and the vowel sound may be reduced to a schwa (or a short /i/), but if an eye-dialect orthographic form is required I'm only really used to seeing ***youse, yous*** (or occasionally ***yez, yers***).